# Why is $x^2+y^2=r^2$ a $1$-sphere and not a $2$-sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Description) a 1-sphere is a circle and a 2-sphere is the ordinary 3-dimensional sphere.

But why are not:

- $x$ a $0$-sphere (just one point)?
- $(x,y)$ a $1$-sphere (a pair of points)?
- $x^2+y^2=r^2$ a $2$-sphere (due to two variables)?
- $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ a $3$-sphere (due to three variables)?

and so on ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $S^1$ lies in $\Bbb R^2$ by definition. The index is a definition. You could rename $S^1$ to $S^2$, for example. But this is not the common definition. The definition is $S^n:=\{x\in \Bbb R^{n+1}\mid \cdots \}$ and $n$ is its **dimension** as a real manifold.

Comment: The definition is associated to the dimension of the sphere. For instance, a circle is an $1-$sphere because it is a line (dimension 1), whereas the $2-$sphere is an surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (dimension 2).

Comment: There are no $0$-spheres.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I see no reason not to think of $\{-r,r\}$ as a $0$-sphere.

Comment: @TonyK: check the first bullet of the OP. This is what I am referring to.

Answer (score 2):

1 is the dimension of the circle itself.  You can identify a point on the circle by specifying one number, say the angle.  (Formally speaking, the circle is a 1-dimensional manifold.) You can imagine the circle as something you get by distorting a line or a piece of string, which are both "manifestly" 1-dimesional.

2 is the dimension of the space it sits in.